# Training data structure and access

Tags: c++, machine-learning, armadillo

I'm writing up an implementation of backpropagation for a feedforward neural network in C++ and I'm using the Armadillo library. Right now, I'm loading training data with the method `load` for the class `matrix` in the Armadillo library. Two questions:

1) Is this a reasonable choice for storing pre-formatted (CSV), numeric data that fits into main memory (<2GB)? Certainly there are better ways to do this than others and it'd be nice to know if this is *not* a good practice. Part of me feels like this isn't a good choice for holding the data as there are likely more data-ish structures/frameworks (like I should be accessing some SQL database or something). Another part of me feels like numeric data is by definition just matrices so this should be wonderful.

2) I need to sample without replacement from a data set in my implementation and I see two routes: either I could shuffle the rows of the data set or shuffle an array that indexes the data set. There is a `shuffle` method for the `matrix` class in the Armadillo library and I'm suspicious that what is shuffled is addresses and not the rows themselves. Wouldn't that be just as efficient as shuffling an indexing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, this is fine and it's how I would do it, but note that Armadillo matrices are column-major and thus you may need to transpose the CSV that you load.  If your data is sufficiently large that it won't fit in main memory, you could consider writing a custom CSV parser that looks at the data in a streaming sense (i.e. one point at a time), thus reducing your RAM footprint, or you could even use `mmap()` to map a file full of packed doubles as your matrix and let the kernel work out what needs to be swapped in when.

2) Because all matrix data is stored contiguously (i.e. `double*` not `double**`), `shuffle()` will be moving the elements in the matrix.  What I generally do in this type of situation is create a vector of indices and shuffle it:

```
uvec indices = linspace<uvec>(0, n, n);
shuffle(indices);
// Now loop over each shuffled point...
for (uword i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  // access the point with data.col(indices[i]) and do whatever
}
```

(The above code isn't tested, but it should work or easily be adapted into something that works.)

For what it's worth, mlpack (http://www.mlpack.org/) does have a not-yet-stable neural network infrastructure that uses Armadillo, and it may be worth your time to check out; the link below is to the relevant source directly, but poking around on Github and the mlpack website should reveal better documentation.

https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/tree/master/src/mlpack/methods/ann